# Android canvas.drawBitmap() rendering bug

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, rendering

[UPDATED with additional code]

I'm having a major problem with Android correctly rendering some bitmaps in my custom view's onDraw() method on some (Nexus 7 and 10 that I know about) but not all devices. It renders properly on the Android phones I have for testing. Here is the snippet of consequence:

```
/* set up mImagePaint earlier */
mImagePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mImagePaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
mImagePaint.setDither(true);
mImagePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
mImagePaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
mImagePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final float vw = getWidth();
    final float vh = getHeight();
    final float bw = mBitmap.getWidth();
    final float bh = mBitmap.getHeight();
    final float ba = bw / bh;
    final float va = vw / vh;
    if (va > ba) {
        final float top = (bh - ba / va * bh) / 2;
        mSrcRect.set(0, (int) top, (int) bw, (int) (bh - top));
    } else {
        final float left = (bw - va / ba * bw) / 2;
        mSrcRect.set((int) left, 0, (int) (bw - left), (int) bh);
    }
    mContentRect.set(0, 0, vw, vh);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mSrcRect, mContentRect, mImagePaint);
}
```

Results on Nexus 7 and 10 are incorrect and renders a wide white border as shown below. This is part of the bitmap rendering but not part of the original bitmap or rect.

[image: Incorrect rendering on Nexus 7]

The correct (desired) result on a Samsung Galaxy phone:

[image: Correct rendering on Samsung Galaxy phone]

The image and code shown in both examples above are exactly the same. I've tried variations already using null paint, null srcRect, and even using alternate method drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null) and get the same results. Looking at the framework code, of course drawBitmap() calls directly to native methods whose source code I can't view.

Only a small number of images seem to exhibit this problem and seems as though mostly square images exhibit it. But here is only one other non-square image that exhibits this problem:

[image: incorrect non-square image on Nexus 7]

Most of these images are slightly rotated given the desired custom view, and it now occurs to me that rotation might be part of the problem, but maybe not since the canvas isn't rotated, just when it's copied to the parent's canvas bitmap backing by Android.

Any ideas? This is nuts!

Comment: could you share a little bit more code? If you are layering surfaceViews then there is no guarantee as to the z ordering, but it isn't clear from your lack of code what you are actually doing

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the pictures are large enough to display without you having to scale up on those devices?

Comment: James, good thought and I thought of that too, but the image is 320x300 and the view rect is smaller. Even if it was smaller, the drawBitmap method should enlarge the source to fit within the view (map from src to dst) and is not.